# Quickest way to get proof of address under lockdown when you've only just arrived in the country?

Tags: united-kingdom

UK.GOV lists [Proof of address](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/proof-of-identity-checklist/proof-of-identity-checklist) as:

> Utility bill (gas, electric, satellite television, landline phone bill) issued within the last three months

With lockdown looming what is the quickest way to obtain proof of address when you've only just arrived in the country?

Comment: I am struggling to understand what difference lockdown makes? Most utility bills these days are available online, or you could call up the supplier and ask them to send you a paper version, if the service you’ve signed up for allows for that (some don’t, or at least not without an extra fee). If you’ve just arrived in the country (per your edit) lockdown doesn't stop you signing up for these services

Comment: Are you in temporary accommodation like a hostel, hotel, or AirBnB?

Comment: @mkennedy Yeah.

Answer (score 1):

If you have any of the domestic accounts listed on the uk.gov webpage at your flat and in your name, the quickest way is to look in your desk, and find the last statement that was mailed to you. Any utility statement will show your name and the account address.

If you don't have a paper statement, you may be able to access your account online, download the statement to your computer, and print a copy.

Comment: I guess I should have been more specific - what's the quickest way when you've only just arrived...oops. I edited my Q now.

Comment: @Mo. The entire right column on the page you linked lists acceptable "Proof of Address" documents. Perhaps "Council or housing association rent card or tenancy agreement for the current year" would work. This does suggest, however, that a short-term rental agreement wouldn't work.